# Finding a critical point

Tags: equation-solving

I hope you can help me find the "critical points" I'm looking for.
For some context: I'm trying to find a critical point in my equations defined as:

```
equation1 = Pi (L - 3)/2 == (L - 2) ArcTan[2 x] + 2 ArcTan[2 (x - alpha)]
equation2 = (d / (1 - d))^2 == ((d^2 + x^2) / ((1 - d)^2 + x^2))^(L-2) * ((d^2 + (x - alpha)^2) / ((1 - d)^2 + (x - alpha)^2))^2
```

and:

```
solL[x_] := L /. Solve[equation1, {L}][[1]];
solD[x_] := d /. NSolve[equation2 /. L -> solL[x], {d}, Reals][[1]]
```

`alpha` is just a constant I fix every case I try to solve.

Due to the symmetries in the equations, only if `alpha={0, L/2, L/4, L}` it is possible to solve this problem analytically. However, I want to be able to find a solution for any fixed `alpha`, so non-analytically. If I plot `solD[x]` it looks like:

[image]

Fixing another value for `alpha` shifts the critical point over the horizontal axis. Now, I am trying to find the critical point `x` (see the red arrow), where my value "hits the ceiling". Anyone an idea how to do this?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please take the [tour]. Here its considered helpful and polite show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly and include the definitions for `differentialEquation`.  Can you please confirm that you mean `NSolve` and not `NDSolve`?

Comment: Hi rhermans, I tried to look up questions in here on stackexchange about finding these kinds of critical points. However so far, I have not found a question/answer that matches my question. I am out of ideas myself on how to do this, so I hope one of the stackexchange smart people can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: We will be happy to help, and point to other answers if available. But first, **we need your help to understand your problem**. This question will be easier to answer and more useful for others if you add a minimal working example of working code and data to show specifically what you are working with. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Include the definition of `differentialEquation` and  please confirm that you mean `NSolve` and not `NDSolve`.

Comment: Very difficult to suggest anything in the absence of a concrete example (as already noted by @rhermans). My guess is a `WhenEvent`, triggered by a large magnitude of a derivative, will be useful for locating such points. A sufficiently large derivative is basically an approximation to a discontinuity.

Comment: `differentialEquation` and `differentialEquation2` are not differential equations, are they?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you're right. I have updated my question, I hope this an improvement for you to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call critical point, is where two solutions of the equation yield both the value 1/2.

Let me write the equations as funtions to be zero.

```
f1 = Pi (L - 3)/2 - ((L - 2) ArcTan[2 x] + 2 ArcTan[2 (x - alpha)]) //Simplify;

sol1 = First@Solve[f1 == 0, L]

(*   {L -> (3 \[Pi] - 4 ArcTan[2 alpha - 2 x] - 4 ArcTan[2 x])/(\[Pi] - 
            2 ArcTan[2 x])}   *)

f2 = (d/(1 - d))^2 - (((d^2 + x^2)/((1 - d)^2 + x^2))^(L - 2)*
      ((d^2 + (x - alpha)^2)/((1 - d)^2 + (x - alpha)^2))^2) // 
    Simplify

f3 = f2 /. sol1 // Simplify
```

ContourPlot shows first, that you have the unique solution d==1/2 for all x and solutions, that drift to higher x for higher alpha, together with your "critical point", where two solutions intersect.

```
ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[Thread[0 == f3 /. alpha -> {0, 2, 4}]], {x, 0, 5}, {d, 0, 
     2}, PlotPoints -> 50, ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

In order to look for the x value, where d gets 1/2 for varying alpha, I took a d near d==1/2, since at exactly d==1/2, f3 is zero.

```
f3 /. d -> 1/2 // FullSimplify[#, x > 0 && alpha > 0] &

(*   0   *)
```

ContourPlot with d near 1/2, shows how the two "critical points" vary with alpha.

```
ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[0 == f3 /. d -> 1/2 - 10^-5], {alpha, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 10}, 
      PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Due to lack of time, I leave you with that qualitative answer.

Comment: This is great. This definitely helped me and I learned some new Mathematica skills... Thanks from the Mathematica-noob speaking here!